# How can I get overflow bin in my histogram using plotly/python

Tags: python, statistics, plotly, histogram

I am using this code to build a histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.histogram(dataset, x="salesperday")

fig.update_traces(xbins=dict( # bins used for histogram
        start=0.0,
        end=1400.0,
        size=40
    ))

fig.show()
```

How can I customize it to get an overflow bin for sales greater than 75 per day just like this i get in excel:

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to bin all outliers into one bin using Histogram in Plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225944/how-to-bin-all-outliers-into-one-bin-using-histogram-in-plotly)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Force values outside range to a_min and a_max
df["salesperday_clip"] = np.clip(salesperday.values, a_min=-0, a_max=75)

fig = px.histogram(df, "salesperday_clip")
```

We use numpy.clip() which forces any values outside the range to a_min or a_max.  The only thing this will not get you is a nice legend with ">75".  You'll need to use plotly (not plotly express) to modify the labels yourself.